# I can no longer edit my iPhone's playlists

Tags: iphone, playlist

My playlists on my iPhone are no longer showing the edit button at the top. Is there a setting for this or anything to get them back?

Comment: I'm assuming these are playlists you're syncing with iTunes? If so, can you try creating a new playlist from your phone to see if the edit button is there?

What version of iOS are you using?

Answer (score 2):

I just answered my own question.  I didn't realize that the list I was trying to edit was a Smart Playlist, which of course assembles lists based on the criteria you set up.  The only way to edit these lists is to change the criteria by which songs are included or modify the songs' information.  My regular playlists have the proper Edit buttons.